# My Vuetify.js app layout fails on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, vuetify.js, grid-system

So I made math tool app with vuetify. To build the contents of tabs, I used the v-row and v-flex components. While it was running on my localhost it worked perfectly on my phone. But now when it's on my website I can zoom out on my phone. It's as if it's in permanent desktop mode. I don't get any errors either.

Has anyone ever faced this issue before?
I built the app with npm run build and put the /dist/ folder on my server.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to update to latest vuetify version. It doesnt use v-flex anymore, but v-col.